# MvvmCross: RaisePropertyChanged not updating binding

Tags: ios, mvvmcross

I am instantiating a view with a ViewModel like this:

```
var myView = new MyView { DataContext = new MyViewModel() };
```

I want to make this view accessible from anywhere in the application so I am adding the view to the  rootviewcontroller:

```
window.RootViewController.View.Add(myView.View);
```

Where ViewModel inherits from MvxViewModel and MyView inherist from MvxViewController

Inside the MyView I am binding a UILabel to a text property like this

```
this.CreateBinding(myLabel).To<MyViewModel>(vm => vm.MyTextProp).Apply();
```

The text property is defined inside the ViewModel like this

```
    private string myTextProp;
    public string MyTextProp
    {
        get { return myTextProp; }
        set
        {
            myTextProp = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyTextProp);
        }
    }
```

The binding works initially when loaded. But when I change the MyTextProp property and RaisePropertyChanged is called the UILabel is not being updated.

I am also binding to an ICommand which works fine and triggers normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `var myView = new MyView { DataContext = new MyViewModel() };`

Let MvvmCross construct your MvxViewController by doing this:

```
var viewController = this.CreateViewControllerFor<MyViewModel>();
```

`CreateViewController` is an extensions method for `IMvxCanCreateTouchView`, so the class where you do your view construction should be implementing that Inteface, otherwise that method will not be available.

I know `IMvxCanCreateTouchView` is implemented by `MvxTouchViewPresenter` and `MvxViewController` so you can call that method from your `Presenter` or from another `MxvViewController`.